# Regex for part of multiline text that includes all kind of characters including newline, @, ^ , ', ",etc

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a large text which is decided in subsection delimited by start and end. I want to extract the text in between unchanged and also extract the name of the part in the text.
I fail as I have used the .+ in my regex I always get the full text. I also had to extract the part name by a different trick as I was not able to catch it in a named group.
So I build a string with the name as input for the regex, but still it fails as .+ is greedy and captures the whole text.

My failed regex:

```
regex_string = '^!!\sSTART\s' + partname + '\s!!(?P<part_text>.*)'
REGEXP_CONTEXT_CONFIG = re.compile(regex_string, re.DOTALL)
```

The test text to capture from:

```
!! START goblin !!
text to capture
that is multiline 
and contains all sort 
of special chars 
!! END goblin !!

!! START berta !!
text to capture
that is multiline 
and contains all sort 
of special chars 
!! END berta !!

!! START vlad !!
text to capture
that is multiline 
and contains all sort 
of special chars 
!! END Vlad !!
```

What I try to archive is a regex that captures the part name and the part of the included text in two named groups.

Comment: So you have all the partnames defined,  right?

Comment: You mention `.+` as greedy, but your regex shows `.*`. Both are greedy, but the difference between your text and example regex can lead to confusion.

Comment: You don't have a finishing marker ("!! END <name> !!") in your regex; is that correct?

Comment: Hi, I have tried .* and .+, both did not work. I have tried a finishing marker, but then the whole regex did not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex like

```
(?smi)^!! START (?P<part_name>goblin|berta|vlad) !!(?P<part_text>.*?)!! END (?P=part_name) !!
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/38OhF3/1/).

**Details**

- `(?smi)` - dot now matches newlines (`s`), `^` also matches start of line (`m`) and the pattern is case insensitive (`i`)
- `^` - start of line
- `!! START`  - literal string
- `(?P<part_name>goblin|berta|vlad)` - Group "part_name" capturing one of the names
- `!!` - literal text
- `(?P<part_text>.*?)` - Group "part_text": any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `!! END`  - literal string
- `(?P=part_name)` - same text as captured in Group "part_name"
- `!!` - literal text.

In code, use

```
partnames = ['goblin', 'berta', 'vlad']
regex_string = '^!! START (?P<part_name>{}) !!(?P<part_text>.*?)!! END (?P=part_name) !!'.format("|".join(partnames))
REGEXP_CONTEXT_CONFIG = re.compile(regex_string, re.DOTALL | re.M| re.I)
print( REGEXP_CONTEXT_CONFIG.findall(text) )
# => [('goblin', '\ntext to capture\nthat is multiline \nand contains all sort \nof special chars \n'), ('berta', '\ntext to capture\nthat is multiline \nand contains all sort \nof special chars \n'), ('vlad', '\ntext to capture\nthat is multiline \nand contains all sort \nof special chars \n')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nOTzUM). You may strip leading/trailing whitespace from the part texts later.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your regex:

- there is no end marker
- greedy patterns can be made non-greedy by putting a question mark after them: `.*?` or `.+?`
- you need to use `re.MULTILINE`, otherwise `^` only matches at the start of the full text (not at the start of each line).
- I've put a 1, 2 or 3 in the example text, otherwise you still wouldn't see if the correct match was made

---

```
text = """
!! START goblin !!
text 1 to capture
that is multiline
and contains all sort
of special chars
!! END goblin !!

!! START berta !!
text 2 to capture
that is multiline
and contains all sort
of special chars
!! END berta !!

!! START vlad !!
text 3 to capture
that is multiline
and contains all sort
of special chars
!! END Vlad !!
"""

import re

partname = "berta"
pattern = '^!!\sSTART\s' + partname + '\s!!(?P<part_text>.*)!!\sEND\s' + partname + '\s!!'
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
match = regex.search(text)
print(match.group('part_text'))
```

Output:

```
text 2 to capture
that is multiline
and contains all sort
of special chars
```

(you may need to play a little to get rid of empty newlines. Or just use `match.group('part_text').strip()`).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a working solutions with the help of the comments and answers here. Many Thanks!

```
re.compile('^!!\sSTART\s(?P<part_name>\w+)\s!!(?P<part_text>.*?)!!\sEND\s\w+\s!!', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```